# What do I need to fix to make this code return "True"?

Tags: python

Here's some code for a project I am working on:

```
# Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True
def the_flying_circus():

    if (3 < 4) and (-10 > -20):# Start coding here!
        print "Hey now!"# Don't forget to indent
        # the code inside this block!
    elif (-4 != -4):
        print "Egad!"# Keep going here.
    else:
         return True # You'll want to add the else statement, too!
```

I am not sure why this doesn't satisfy the condition of having the code return `True`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Because the expression `(3 < 4) and (-10 > -20)` will always be `True`? Or am I misunderstanding your question here?

Comment: `else` will only be executed if none of the previous `if` clauses is true. Since the first condition is true, else will not be executed. If you always want to return true, put it outside of the `else` branch.

Comment: try `print the_flying_circus()`

Comment: Lukas Graf is correct.  Further to that, having ambiguous return values is not good form. Return a tuple with (text, bool) and deal with the printing outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition is always `TRUE`:

```
if (3 < 4) and (-10 > -20):# Start coding here!
    print "Hey now!"# Don't forget to indent
    # the code inside this block!
```

So the script will always print: `Hey now!`.
There is no chance, the code will ends in any of these conditions.

```
elif (-4 != -4):
    print "Egad!"# Keep going here.
else:
     return True # You'll want to add the else statement, too!
```

These conditions are absolutely unnecessary. Only thing you can do is change the first condition (e.g. use some variable, which will take different values so the condition won't be `TRUE` every time)

Answer (score 2):

```
(3 < 4) and (-10 > -20)
```

Well, 3 is less than 4. And `-10` is greater than `-20`. So that expression is always true. Your function does not execute a return statement and so returns `None`. Your function could be re-written like this:

```
def the_flying_circus():
    print "Hey now!"
    return None
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by adding the line return True after the if statement (indented, of course) and removed the print command. Basically, I didn't realize that I had to code the "return True" part...I was assuming that Python knew that what I had typed was true. Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

```
# Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True def the_flying_circus():

    if (3 < 4) and (-10 > -20):# Start coding here!
        print "Hey now!"# Don't forget to indent
        # the code inside this block!
    elif (-4 != -4):
        print "Egad!"# Keep going here.
    return True # You'll want to add the else statement, too!
```

This returns `True`. Otherwise, you're always going to get "Hey now!" because your `if` condition is always `True`.

If you want to return `True` when the condition is met, then the code should be

```
if (3 < 4) and (-10 > -20):# Start coding here!
            print "Hey now!"
            return True
```

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed that the return True can come before the print command. So depending on one's preference, you can have it return before print or vice-versa (not sure why that would matter, though, in this case).

Comment: If you return before the print statement, the print wouldn't execute.